# how to save an image in uitableviewcell to album with long tap

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I use following code to get images from internet

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
   NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",image_url, [dic objectForKey:@"imageurl"]]];
__block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
__weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.userinformationimageView;
cell.userinformationimageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[cell.userinformationimageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
    if (!activityIndicator) {
        [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite]];
        activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
        [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    }
} completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    activityIndicator = nil;
}];
//more codes
}
```

there are so many cells and each cell has a image, and I add long tap

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPressGr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressToDo:)];
longPressGr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
[self.tableview addGestureRecognizer:longPressGr];

- (void)longPressToDo:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
if(gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.tableview];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:point];
    if(indexPath == nil) return;
    NSLog(@"---->%d",[indexPath row]);
    NSDictionary *dic = [self.tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

}
}
```

so how can I get the image that i long tapped? I want to save it to album, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simpler cleaner solution to what you are trying to do. I would probably do it like this

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@",image_url, [dic objectForKey:@"imageurl"]]];
    __block UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
    __weak UIImageView *weakImageView = cell.userinformationimageView;

    cell.userinformationimageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    //Instead of whole TableView add the gesture to the Image itself
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer * longPressGr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressToDo:)];
    longPressGr.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [cell.userinformationimageView addGestureRecognizer:longPressGr];
     cell.userinformationimageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [cell.userinformationimageView sd_setImageWithURL:imageUrl placeholderImage:nil options:SDWebImageProgressiveDownload progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {
        if (!activityIndicator) {
            [weakImageView addSubview:activityIndicator = [UIActivityIndicatorView.alloc initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite]];
            activityIndicator.center = weakImageView.center;
            [activityIndicator startAnimating];
        }
    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
       [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
       activityIndicator = nil;
    }];
//more codes
}
```

And in the gesture handler function do this

```
- (void)longPressToDo:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
      //Just to be sure and avoid crashes
      if ([recognizer.view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] ) {
         //Get the ImageView 
         UIImageView *temp = (UIImageView*)recognizer.view;
         UIImage *requiredImage = temp.image;
         //Do whatever you want with the image
    }     
}
```

So basically what is happening here is instead of the whole tableview you are attaching the gesture to your Image, and when the gesture happens in the handler of you get access to the UIImageView calling the gesture and can get the Image from it. You can also attach the Gesture to the whole individual Cell (not sure what your use case is) and similarly extract the ImageView and the Image for your usage.

Comment: ohh one more thing, you need to set interaction enabled for UIImageView, by default its off. let me fix the answer

Comment: I edited the answer, did it work for you (I tested it on my side but just curious if I left something out)